# {v r s} signature to string

Tags: signature

I'm working with rarible API and for one request it's needed to provide a signature as a string.

I have a signature object {
"v": 28,
"r": "0xda4429a9e8e6b54cb101b2df002039f2879ab4ca0e8fae64134942cb81f3e581",
"s": "0x3b90a37dc078a82dfc418695b1d4473661aa4d24dd874ac68678894ff44a6b27"
}

How can I turn this object into a signature string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get this and more information by looking up RLP Encoding in Ethereum's Yellow Paper, as is explained [here](https://eth.wiki/fundamentals/rlp). To directly answer your question for **your case**:

Signature format is v ++ (length(r) + 0x80 ) ++ r ++ (length(s) + 0x80) ++ s, where + means addition and ++ means concatenation. Notice that length here means the amount of bytes, so that means the amount of symbols in hex divided by two.

In your case, this would lead to

```
0x28 ++ (0x20 + 0x80) ++ 0xda4429a9e8e6b54cb101b2df002039f2879ab4ca0e8fae64134942cb81f3e581 ++  (0x20 + 0x80) ++ 0x3b90a37dc078a82dfc418695b1d4473661aa4d24dd874ac68678894ff44a6b27
```

and result in the following signature string:

```
0x28a0da4429a9e8e6b54cb101b2df002039f2879ab4ca0e8fae64134942cb81f3e581a03b90a37dc078a82dfc418695b1d4473661aa4d24dd874ac68678894ff44a6b27
```

Notice how I am implicitly assuming your provided v is already in hex format although it does not start with 0x. If this result differs from your expectation, try converting v to its hex representation and following the same process I just described with the converted value.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. It helps a lot. When I plug your result the API claims that it's too long. Invalid signature size 67, should be 65 bytes

Any clue how to reduce the size but keep the signature? I think Rarible expects a certain format. I wish they had an example request, but I can't find anything like that

Comment: My original answers refers to signatures for signed transactions. It could be that Rarible wants just normal ECDSA signatures, in which case your signature is just r ++ s ++ v.

Comment: Let me know if this turned out to be the case and I will edit my original answer accordingly

Comment: Turned out rarible have their own way to deal with signatures. They just conc the values. Thank you for your help 